# Stack Exchange v2.2 PHP API Client

Tags: app, php

I am developing a PHP library for interacting with the Stack Exchange API.

Most of the methods are unimplemented so far.

I am writing this post because I need to test some auth methods.

My app source code is at [GitHub: benatespina/StackExchangeApiClient](https://github.com/benatespina/StackExchangeApiClient).

Comment: If you have improves about the library, please tell me :)

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**If someone wants to contribute:**

This projects follows PHP coding standards, so pull requests need to execute the Fabien Potencier's [PHP-CS-Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/)
and Marc Morera's [PHP-Formatter](https://github.com/mmoreram/php-formatter). Furthermore, if the PR creates some not-PHP file remember that you have to put
the license header manually.

```
$ vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix
$ vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --config-file .phpspec_cs

$ vendor/bin/php-formatter formatter:use:sort
$ vendor/bin/php-formatter formatter:header:fix
```

There is also a policy for contributing to this project. Pull requests must be explained step by step to make the
review process easy in order to accept and merge them. New methods or code improvements must come paired with
[PHPSpec](http://www.phpspec.net/) tests.