# Can we change the Stack Apps homepage tabs to not show questions tagged "obsolete" and "placeholder"?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, meta, design, front-page

Following [What should we do about dead listings?](https://stackapps.com/q/7983), we've started to add [obsolete](/questions/tagged/obsolete) to questions that are 'deprecated, no longer available/supported, or no longer relevant'.

However, on the front page, there are a few [obsolete](/questions/tagged/obsolete) question ('apps' tab):

[image: 'obsolete' questions shown on front page]

There are also lots of [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder) questions shown:

[image: 'placeholder' questions shown on front page]

Could the system please take [obsolete](/questions/tagged/obsolete) and [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder) into account?

It would help to make the active and working apps more visible to casual users.

---

Also, as you can see from the right of the above screenshot, post author names are cut off -- could that be fixed too?

Comment: Looks like the last line warrants a separate post.

Comment: Also, there's a workaround, in case you haven't opted to grey ignored tags out: ignore [tag:obsolete] and [tag:placeholder], and hide ignored tags.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος, I think that name cutoff has been brought up before either here or on [metase].  Don't have a post link handy at the moment though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the homepage is not showing *Stack Apps* in its best light.

As a mitigation that we can all do now:

#### Prepend "OBSOLETE - " or "PLACEHOLDER - " to the title, if appropriate.

(In addition to those 2 tags.)

---

Note that Power users can grey out or hide such questions:

[image: hide the cruft]